# jquery plugin for ratings (bar style)

Tags: jquery

'm looking for a jquery rating plugin(non-star) that looks something like the picture below. I was wondering if anyone knows of one?

[image]

I could just create an image and display it but it would be nice if there was something out there already with a cool animation.

thanks
jquery